sinon stub error with ava " Attempted to wrap myFunction which is already wrapped" despite using sinon.sandbox
I'm encountering an issue with Sinon while running my tests in parallel mode using Ava. Whenever I run my tests with ava --parallel, I get the following error:
beforeEach hook for myfile

Error thrown in test:

TypeError: Attempted to wrap myFunction which is already wrapped

Here's a simplified version of my test setup:
import sinon from 'sinon';
import * as myModule from '../../../src/myModule';

test.beforeEach(t => {
  t.context.sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
  t.context.sandbox.stub(myModule, 'myFunction').returns(false);
});

test.afterEach.always(t => {
  t.context.sandbox.restore();
});

What I've Tried:
Serial Execution: When I run my tests with ava --serial, everything works fine without any errors.
Check for Duplicate Stubs: I've verified that the myFunction function is only being stubbed once in my test setup and is not being stubbed elsewhere in my test file.
Additional Information:
The myFunction function is a top-level function in the myModule module and is being stubbed in a beforeEach hook for each test.
Question:
What could be causing this "attempted to wrap already wrapped function" error when running tests in parallel mode with Sinon, and how can I resolve it? I cannot seem to understand why it would try re-wrapping the same stub, if the point of the sandbox env is for each test to have it's own instance

You are correct in pointing out that, we get the error attempted to wrap already wrapped function when the same function being stubbed multiple times.
Given that beforeEach gets executed before each test, while running the second test it will again try to stub the same function.
If its working in serial run then that will be due to the t.context.sandbox.restore(); in the afterEach hook.
Check and move the test.beforeEach() statements to test.before()
